# how to know that where exactly app getting stuck in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

My app gets stuck for a specific operation and that operation is too big having so many method calls and services requests, so i cannot put breakpoints on each method and debug, is there any other way i can get to know where exactly my app is stucked in xcode?

Comment: use time profiler in instruments. where u can see which process take much time

Answer (score 0):

The operation wasn't too big to write the code, so it isn't too big to add breakpoints, logging statements, assertions and so on.

The only other way that works sometimes is taking a long shower in the morning, not thinking about work at all, and suddenly the realisation what you did wrong jumps to your mind. It has worked for me sometimes, but the first method is more reliable.

Comment: yeah you are right, but the thing is this app was developed by someone else. So its hard for me to understand full flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have reason to believe that the most time is spent in one operation, just let it run with the debugger attached and then press the pause button and see where you are...

A somewhat niftier approach would be to start with Instruments (i.e. the Time Profiler). It's easy to use and should be the first weapon of your choice for performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a conditional break point in Xcode to debug a specific condition, for more detail go through [Jeffrey Sambells blog](http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode)!